# How to prevent buttons from submitting forms

Tags: javascript, html

In the following page, with Firefox the remove button submits the form, but the add button does not.

How do I prevent the `remove` button from submitting the form?

```js
function addItem() {
  var v = $('form :hidden:last').attr('name');
  var n = /(.*)input/.exec(v);

  var newPrefix;
  if (n[1].length == 0) {
    newPrefix = '1';
  } else {
    newPrefix = parseInt(n[1]) + 1;
  }

  var oldElem = $('form tr:last');
  var newElem = oldElem.clone(true);
  var lastHidden = $('form :hidden:last');

  lastHidden.val(newPrefix);

  var pat = '=\"' + n[1] + 'input';

  newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(new RegExp(pat, 'g'), '=\"' + newPrefix + 'input'));
  newElem.appendTo('table');
  $('form :hidden:last').val('');
}

function removeItem() {
  var rows = $('form tr');
  if (rows.length > 2) {
    rows[rows.length - 1].html('');
    $('form :hidden:last').val('');
  } else {
    alert('Cannot remove any more rows');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
        <p>Title:<input type="text" /></p>
        <button onclick="addItem(); return false;">Add Item</button>
        <button onclick="removeItem(); return false;">Remove Last Item</button>
        <table>
            <th>Name</th>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" /></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="input2" name="input2" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2544):

You're using an HTML5 button element. Remember the reason is this button has a default behavior of submit, as stated in the W3 specification as seen here:
[W3C HTML5 Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

So you need to specify its type explicitly:

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

in order to override the default submit type. I just want to point out the reason why this happens.

Comment: I also wish to point out that a HTML element having a type attribute, one of the types of which is *button*, should not f#$'n have a default type of *submit*. It's just plain idiotic, and a huge mistake in the spec. I use buttons in forms all the time, and even if it were an edge case (which it isn't), it'd still make sense to have the default type be submit.

Comment:  I've spent most of this week annoyed that my Electron app "refreshed" when I open a modal using a button within a form. It'd happen once and then the app behaved as I expected. I had absolutely no idea what was going on. This was it! I have no issue with the default type being submit. It seems a bit of a gotcha though given it has taken me five years to learn about it.

Comment: Thanks to your reference, I've just learned that there's a type=reset for form. Awesome!

Comment: There are advantages as every button event includes the enclosing form element and thus has access to the elements as `formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(evt.target))`

Comment: I know it doesn't add any value but this is the best answer I've ever seen on SO. The simplest solution 

Comment: I share sentiment here. Having button have any other default type than "button" is simply asinine. As it's completely unintuitive (and invisible - making it very hard to nail down - as it's the default and wasn't something I added to the element). I spent the better part of 2 hours trying to figure out why pressing "enter" in an input box was selecting the first button in the form and clicking it. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Well. What do you know. 10+ years into this profession and I'm learning this bit of info just now. We learn new stuff every dawn I guess. :D

Comment: this answer not working. but don't know why people upvoting this answer.

Comment: @Metafaniel in 2022, now it doesn't work at react. I don't know if it works in HTML.  instead of `button` you have to use `<input type="button" value="button"/>`

Comment: @HNazmulHassan The official HTML5 specification is helpful in many contexts. Even if the answer didn't work for you in your React project as is, it may have have been helpful in some way.

Comment: Thank you. This is annoying me, It was a complete oversite on my part, as I have two sections of button rows, and the bottom section had the type=button in it, but the top section was missing it for some reason, and I could not for the life of me figure out why it was submitting the form. Thank you.

Answer (score 660):

Set the type on your buttons:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addItem(); return false;">Add Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeItem(); return false;">Remove Last Item</button>
```

...that'll keep them from triggering a submit action when an exception occurs in the event handler. Then, fix your `removeItem()` function so that it doesn't trigger an exception:

```
function removeItem() {
  var rows = $('form tr');
  if ( rows.length > 2 ) {
    // change: work on filtered jQuery object
    rows.filter(":last").html('');
    $('form :hidden:last').val('');
  } else {
    alert('Cannot remove any more rows');
  }
}
```

Note the change: your original code extracted a HTML element from the jQuery set, and then tried to call a jQuery method on it - this threw an exception, resulting in the default behavior for the button.

FWIW, there's another way you could go with this... Wire up your event handlers using jQuery, and use the [preventDefault()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) method on jQuery's [event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) object to cancel the default behavior up-front:

```
$(function() // execute once the DOM has loaded
{

  // wire up Add Item button click event
  $("#AddItem").click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

    //... rest of add logic
  });

  // wire up Remove Last Item button click event
  $("RemoveLastItem").click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

    //... rest of remove last logic
  });

});

...

<button type="button" id="AddItem" name="AddItem">Add Item</button>
<button type="button" id="RemoveLastItem" name="RemoveLastItem">Remove Last Item</button>
```

This technique keeps all of your logic in one place, making it easier to debug... it also allows you to implement a fall-back by changing the `type` on the buttons back to `submit` and handling the event server-side - this is known as [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: type="button" doesn't always work in Firefox for me. If the js is complicated enough, and there's an error Firefox will submit the form anyway. Insanity!

Comment: @MatthewLock: Hardly - an error in the script just shuts down that code block, and the action proceeds as usual. Try invoking the jQuery event methods e.preventDefault() and/or e.stopPropgation() as the first lines of the method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017755/whats-the-difference-between-e-preventdefault-and-return-false to learn more

Comment: type=button should never submit the form though, no matter what

Comment: `return false` is so important. sometimes even use it for submit button (`onclick`）

Comment: I think html is strange here. It should be type="button" by default, not submitting. It's always unexpected to me to see that submit by default. It's the exception.

Comment: Consider that `type="button"` is completely useless unless you wire up a script, @httpete. Granted, that's a pretty common use-case - but if you're going out of your way to specify non-default behavior *anyway*...

Comment: +1 for 'there's an unhandled exception somewhere in your event handler,' which is the root cause--why `return false;` wasn't enough to prevent the submit.

Answer (score 39):

Sometime ago I needed something very similar... and I got it.

So what I put here is how I do the tricks to have a form able to be submitted by JavaScript without any validating and execute validation only when the user presses a button (typically a send button).

For the example I will use a minimal form, only with two fields and a submit button.

Remember what is wanted:
From JavaScript it must be able to be submitted without any checking. However, if the user presses such a button, the validation must be done and form sent only if pass the validation.

Normally all would start from something near this (I removed all extra stuff not important):

```
<form method="post" id="theFormID" name="theFormID" action="">
   <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" />
   <input type="text" id="Field2" name="Field2" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator();" />
</form>
```

See how form tag has no `onsubmit="..."` (remember it was a condition not to have it).

The problem is that the form is always submitted, no matter if `onclick` returns `true` or `false`.

If I change `type="submit"` for `type="button"`, it seems to work but does not. It never sends the form, but that can be done easily.

So finally I used this:

```
<form method="post" id="theFormID" name="theFormID" action="">
   <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" />
   <input type="text" id="Field2" name="Field2" />
   <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator();" />
</form>
```

And on `function Validator`, where `return True;` is, I also add a JavaScript submit sentence, something similar to this:

```
function Validator(){
   //  ...bla bla bla... the checks
   if(                              ){
      document.getElementById('theFormID').submit();
      return(true);
   }else{
      return(false);
   }
}
```

The `id=""` is just for JavaScript `getElementById`, the `name=""` is just for it to appear on POST data.

On such way it works as I need.

I put this just for people that need no `onsubmit` function on the form, but make some validation when a button is press by user.

Why I need no onsubmit on form tag? Easy, on other JavaScript parts I need to perform a submit but I do not want there to be any validation.

The reason: If user is the one that performs the submit I want and need the validation to be done, but if it is JavaScript sometimes I need to perform the submit while such validations would avoid it.

It may sounds strange, but not when thinking for example: on a Login ... with some restrictions... like not allow to be used PHP sessions and neither cookies are allowed!

So any link must be converted to such form submit, so the login data is not lost.
When no login is yet done, it must also work. So no validation must be performed on links.
But I want to present a message to the user if the user has not entered both fields, user and pass. So if one is missing, the form must not be sent! there is the problem.

See the problem: the form must not be sent when one field is empty only if the user has pressed a button, if it is a JavaScript code it must be able to be sent.

If I do the work on `onsubmit` on the form tag, I would need to know if it is the user or other JavaScript. Since no parameters can be passed, it is not possible directly, so some people add a variable to tell if validation must be done or not. First thing on validation function is to check that variable value, etc... Too complicated and code does not say what is really wanted.

So the solution is not to have onsubmit on the form tag. Insead put it where it really is needed, on the button.

For the other side, why put onsubmit code since conceptually I do not want onsubmit validation. I really want button validation.

Not only the code is more clear, it is where it must be. Just remember this:
- I do not want JavaScript to validate the form (that must be always done by PHP on the server side)
- I want to show to the user a message telling all fields must not be empty, that needs JavaScript (client side)

So why some people (think or tell me) it must be done on an onsumbit validation? No, conceptually I am not doing a onsumbit validating at client side. I am just doing something on a button get pressed, so why not just let that to be implemented?

Well that code and style does the trick perfectly.  On any JavaScript that I need to send the form I just put:

```
document.getElementById('theFormID').action='./GoToThisPage.php'; // Where to go
document.getElementById('theFormID').submit(); // Send POST data and go there
```

And that skips validation when I do not need it. It just sends the form and loads a different page, etc.

But if the user clicks the submit button (aka `type="button"` not `type="submit"`) the validation is done before letting the form be submitted and if not valid not sent.

Well hope this helps others not to try long and complicated code. Just not use `onsubmit` if not needed, and use `onclick`. But just remember to change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and please do not forget to do the `submit()` by JavaScript.

Answer (score 32):

I agree with Shog9, though I might instead use:

```
<input type = "button" onClick="addItem(); return false;" value="Add Item" />
```

[According to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_button.asp), the `<button>` tag has different behavior on different browsers.

Answer (score 29):

You can simply get the reference of your buttons using jQuery, and prevent its propagation like below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#BUTTON_ID').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            return false;
    });});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` is enough for things to work.
`e.stopImmediatePropagation()` this throws an error of undefined method in Chrome.

Answer (score 22):

`$("form").submit(function () { return false; });` 
that will prevent the button from submitting or you can just change the button type to "button" `<input type="button"/>` instead of `<input type="submit"/>`
Which will only work if this button isn't the only button in this form.

Comment: This is for jQuery, an equivalent in Javascript is: myform.onsubmit = function() {return false} ... also, even if you remove the submit button, the form could also be submitted by pressing enter from another form field.

Answer (score 21):

Suppose your HTML form has `id="form_id"`

```
<form id="form_id">
<!--your HTML code-->
</form>
```

Add this jQuery snippet to your code to see result,

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Buttons like `<button>Click to do something</button>` are submit buttons.

You must add `type`

Answer (score 14):

This is an html5 error like has been said, you can still have the button as a submit (if you want to cover both javascript and non javascript users) using it like:

```
     <button type="submit" onclick="return false"> Register </button>
```

This way you will cancel the submit but still do whatever you are doing in jquery or javascript function`s and do the submit for users who dont have javascript.

Answer (score 13):

Just add `e.preventDefault();` in your method should prevent your page from submitting forms.

```
function myFunc(e){
       e.preventDefault();
}
```

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> The preventDefault () method of the Event interface tells the user
>   agent that if the event is not explicitly processed, its default
>   action should not be taken into account as it would normally be. The
>   event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its listeners
>   calls `stopPropagation ()` or `stopImmediatePropagation ()`, either of
>   which terminates the propagation.

Answer (score 11):

The return false prevents the default behavior. but the return false breaks the bubbling of additional click events. This means if there are any other click bindings after this function gets called, those others do not Consider.

```
 <button id="btnSubmit" type="button">PostData</button>
 <Script> $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
   // do stuff
   return false;
}); </Script>
```

Or simply you can put like this

```
 <button type="submit" onclick="return false"> PostData</button>
```

Answer (score 11):

if you have `<input />`

use it

```
<input type="button"/>
```

if you have `<button>btn</button>`

use it

```
<button type="button">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

I am sure that on FF the

```
removeItem
```

function encounter a JavaScript error, this not happend on IE

When javascript error appear the "return false" code won't run, making the page to postback

Answer (score 6):

> Set your button in normal way and use event.preventDefault like..

```
   <button onclick="myFunc(e)"> Remove </button>  
   ...
   ...

   In function...

   function myFunc(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
return false;
```

You can return false at the end of the function or after the function call.

Just as long as it's the last thing that happens, the form will not submit.

Comment: If you have the "required" attribute on the fields associated with the button it disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){

    /* Perform some button action ... */
    alert("I don't like it when you press my button!");

    /* Then, the most important part ... */
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test this right now, but I would think you could use jQuery's [preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) method.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample code show you how to prevent button click from submitting form.

You may try my sample code:

```
 <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
   <p>Title:
     <input type="text" />
   </p>
   <input type="button" onclick="addItem()" value="Add Item">
   <input type="button" onclick="removeItem()" value="Remove Last Item">
   <table>
     <th>Name</th>

     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="hidden" id="input2" name="input2" />
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
<script language="javascript">
function addItem() {
return false;
}

function removeItem() {
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function removeItem actually contains an error, which makes the form button do it's default behaviour (submitting the form). The javascript error console will usually give a pointer in this case.

Check out the function removeItem in the javascript part:

The line:

```
rows[rows.length-1].html('');
```

doesn't work. Try this instead:

```
rows.eq(rows.length-1).html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Do your logic on the form onsubmit event

> submitter Read only
> An HTMLElement object which identifies the button or other element which was invoked to trigger the form being submitted.

```
onsubmit="(evt) => console.log(evt)"
```

The event itself will bring along the caller and some usefull info.

Just use evt.preventDefault(); (default submit) evt.stopPropagation(); (submit bubbling) if the caller is a