# controller method not returning any response after successful execution

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am posting my data using Ajax, the data is successfully posted to the database. But I am not getting response back from the `Create` Method.
I mean return `RedirectToAction("Index");` the page is not redirecting to Index page.

```
// POST: TestModels/Create        
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TestModel testModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TestModels.Add(testModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(testModel);
}
```

Also, I tried:

```
// POST: TestModels/Create        
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(TestModel testModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TestModels.Add(testModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
       return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
    }
    return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Still I am not getting any `Json` response.

My javascript function::

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_submit').click(function () {

            var testModel = {
                FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
                LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                Gender: $("input[name='Gender']:checked").val(),
                Contact: $('#Contact').val(),
                Faculty: $('#Faculty').val(),
                RegNepaliDate: $('#RegNepaliDate').val()
            };
            alert(JSON.stringify(testModel));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/TestModels/Create", 
                data: JSON.stringify(testModel),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("failed...");
                  }  
            })

        })
    })
</script>
```

The data is posted to the server and when I browse `Index` page the newly inserted data is also shown.
Also, when I click the submit button of the `Create` page, the form data becomes clear but all the data is shown in the url bar

https://localhost:44399/TestModels/Create?FirstName=machhi&LastName=go&Gender=male&Contact=5589512369&Faculty=science&RegNepaliDate=2021-05-01

Comment: In Chrome, press F12 and switch to network tab and monitor the post request? Does it return a 200 status code?

Comment: Can you show you view too, pls?

Comment: @Greg While debugging using firefox developer tool, in Network -> POST method showing NS_BINDING_ABORTED in `Transferred` tab.

Comment: NS_BINDING_ABORTED might be a Firefox specific issue. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704561/ns-binding-aborted-shown-in-firefox-with-httpfox. I would recommend debugging your code with Chrome, to find out the response of the POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please add missing jQuery library file like "

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

" to get the response from Controller.

Comment: I have already added the above scripts in my page, but still not working. Please help...

Comment: did you debug error response in ajax? and what error it returns

Comment: While debugging using firefox developer tool, in Network -> POST method showing NS_BINDING_ABORTED in `Transferred` tab.