# NS_BINDING_ABORTED error in react useEffect() when using window.location.replace()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firefox, next.js, window.location

Ok I get this `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` error in Firefox. So in my react component I want to redirect to another page when the user opens this page.

Here's the code:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const Redirect = function () {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.replace('https://google.com')
  }, [])

  return null
}

export default Redirect
```

BTW it works perfectly fine in Google Chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NS_BINDING_ABORTED Shown in Firefox with HttpFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704561/ns-binding-aborted-shown-in-firefox-with-httpfox)?